# I am not able to import project from SVN Repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to import projects from SVN Repository but it is failing quoting multiple reasons.

> Failed to load JavaHL Library. These are the errors that were
>   encountered:
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\ssleay32.dll:
>   The operating system cannot run %1 Native Library
>   C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll already loaded in another classloader
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvn_delta-1.dll:
>   The specified procedure could not be found
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvn_diff-1.dll:
>   The specified procedure could not be found
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvn_wc-1.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvn_fs-1.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvn_repos-1.dll:
>   The specified procedure could not be found
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvn_ra-1.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvn_client-1.dll:
>   The specified procedure could not be found
>   E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0.cp\libsvnjavahl-1.dll:
>   The specified procedure could not be found no svnjavahl-1 in
>   java.library.path no svnjavahl in java.library.path java.library.path
>   = E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\Varun.Jain\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;E:\Softwares\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.

[image: Native Library Error]

And when I am trying to access SVN from Eclipse Preferences then again it is giving me **org/tmatesoft/sqljet/core/SqlJetException** and not letting me choose anything from it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use subclipse plugin inside Eclipse? Did you install the SVN Kit part too? Without it subversion won't work, anyway if reinstall of Subclipse plugin is not help, I recommend you to do these steps:

1. install full Silk SVN client (https://sliksvn.com/download/)
2. Add the bin directory of it to system path.
3. Restart Eclipse

and it will work.